# How can i do a "complete" reset of Ubuntu 14.04, WITHOUT using a disk or USB drive?

Tags: software-installation, reset

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 that is booted with Ubuntu 14.04. It is becoming very unstable, crashing, failing to go through with commands entered into the terminal, and is beginning to shut down without warning.

It will NOT allow me to delete any programs installed from the Ubuntu Software Center in order to make room for the latest updates. I am desperately hoping that there is a way without using USB or disk.

Comment: Try removing those applications using apt-get and please post the errors if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option, you could setup a network boot server to boot over LAN, have a look at this program, it can easily transmit your Ubuntu ISO over your local network: http://www.aomeitech.com/pxe/pxe-boot-software.html
It's free to download for Windows. If your other computer is also installed with Linux, it's a bit more involved, but on the Ubuntu Wiki you should be able to find the article on how to setup PXEBoot.